# How to send request with param to my server from shopify app admin area

Tags: php, shopify

I am working in shopify and I am new I added form inside the iframe of my public app see https://snag.gy/P3QpXl.jpg

NOw what i need is I would like to store that value in my database how we can send request to my server with form parameters so I Can save that all form data in my db 
Here is my form code

```
 <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
          <div class="row collapse">
            <label>Title</label>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" name="title" />
            </div>
            <label>Description</label>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Product Description" name="body_html" />
            </div>
            <label>Image Url</label>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Image Url" name="image_src" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <button class="button product_submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here is below script i am not sure if there is other shopify way to send data to my server

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  <script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.init({
      apiKey: "api_key",
      shopOrigin: 'domin'
    });
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.product_submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: '/products',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
         // ShopifyApp.flashNotice("Product Uploaded Successfully");
          $('form')[0].reset();
        },
        error: function() {
            //ShopifyApp.flashError("Warning: Product Uploaded Failed");
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
```

I would like this save data when i click on https://snag.gy/luEKcP.jpg **Save** button that i created using below code

```
ShopifyApp.flashError("Warning: Product Uploaded Failed");
    ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'upsell-hero/assets/images/logo.png',
        buttons: {
            primary: {
                label: "Save",
                message: 'bar_save'
            },
```

});